# why the AJAX request in my page just works once

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

i am writing a online tictactoe game and i have a function in javascript that check that if some where clicked in the screen is not X or O then mark it with X or O and then update the database where is clicked. here is my javascript code in play.php page (this is in  ) where check that with `isEmpty` function . `path` is the variable that detect which cells in tictactoe is clicked(from 1 to 9) :

```
....
if (isEmpty(xBoard, oBoard, bit)) {
    path.push(y*3+x+1);
    alert(path);
    markBit(bit, playerXO);
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "gameProcess.php",
           data: {
                    'ID' : path
                    },
           dataType: "json",

           success: function(){
                alert('success');

           },
    });
....
```

i use ajax to update something in database with PHP (gameProcess.php) and send 'ID' value to write in a table of mysql Database.here is my gameProcess.php code:

```
<?php

function post($key) {
if (isset($_POST[$key]))
    return $_POST[$key];
return false;
}

// setup the database connect
$cxn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Mazda1428');
if (!$cxn)
exit;
mysql_select_db('irgc', $cxn);

// check if we can get hold of the form field
if (!post('ID'))
exit;

// let make sure we escape the data
$val = mysql_real_escape_string(post('ID'), $cxn);

// lets setup our insert query
$sql = "UPDATE  game SET sequence=".$val." WHERE id = 2;";

// lets run our query
$result = mysql_query($sql, $cxn);

// setup our response "object"
$resp = new stdClass();
$resp->success = false;
if($result) {
$resp->success = true;
}

print json_encode($resp);
?>
```

but when i open the browser and go in play.php and click in tictactoe game the first time is OK. but after that no thing will add in DB (but still i see the alert('success')).
finally,sorry for bad english.

Comment: What is your `isEmpty` function like? Did you try alerting inside that `if` block wherein which has that function? That every time you click on the board, it is detected properly?

Comment: isEmpty checks that if a cell in tictactoe is empty then mark it as X or O this is works fine but when i use ajax database update only first time that this function is called

Answer (score 0):

disable `cache` and try again.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       cache: false,

       url: "gameProcess.php",
       data: {
                'ID' : path
                },
       dataType: "json",

       success: function(){
            alert('success');

       },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should add a random URL address parameter